# Make Chrome dev tools dock to bottom if browser width below value

Tags: google-chrome

I was wondering if it is possible to make chrome dev tools dock to the bottom of the screen automatically if the browser width is below a certain value, and to the right if above said value - I resize my browser window alot to test different media queries, and although my first preference is to have the dev tools docked to the right, it would be great if it could automatically snap to the bottom below say 768px

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible, you have to rearrange it every time you do this. But you can also move the Chrome Developer Tools to a separate window.

Comment: Thanks for answering, dug around a little more and can't find anything else on the matter so you must be correct - I guess noone else is as lazy as me!